# Node.js Cluster - unable to close http.Server or exit process

Tags: node.js

I'm currently using node's Cluster module to make use of multiple cores.  However, I am unable to gracefully shut down a worker on node 0.10.18 using the following - see function serverClose():

[master.js]

```
cluster.on('disconnect', function(worker) {
    console.log('exit #4')
});

cluster.on('exit', function(worker) {
    console.log('exit #5')
});
```

[worker.js]

```
server = http.createServer(function(req,res) {
    //
}).on('close', function() {
    console.log('exit #1')
    process.exit();
}).listen(80);

function serverClose() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('exit #2')
        process.exit();
    }, 1000 * 5);

    server.close(function() {
        console.log('exit #3')
        process.exit();
    });
}
```

The http server correctly stops accepting incoming connections, however would it surprise you to learn that none of the log statements will fire?  The server stops but the process will not exit and sp the cluster does not create a new worker.

---

[EDIT]

Thanks to Laurent, the following seems to be working reliably for me:

[master.js]

```
cluster.on('disconnect', function(worker) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        worker.kill();
    }, 1000 * 30);
    cluster.fork();
});
```

[worker.js]

```
server = http.createServer(function(req,res) {
    //
}).listen(80);

function serverClose() {
    var killTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('this never fires, so the process must be shut down by the master');
        process.exit(1);
    }, 1000 * 15);
    killTimeout.unref();

    server.close();

    cluster.worker.disconnect();
}
```

I still don't know why the worker's timeout will not fire, but as long as it gets closed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the [cluster example](http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html#domain_warning_don_t_ignore_errors) in the domain documentation.

Interesting bits:

- You can manually disconnect the worker with `cluster.worker.disconnect()`.
- You can prevent a `setTimeout` from keeping the process alive with `timeout.unref()`.
- `server.close` will wait for all connections to terminate before calling the callback, which might take a while.

Comment: 1.  if worker.disconnect() will safely close the server, waiting for requests to complete, then i could use this... but then i would also need process.send()
2.  could an timeout or interval also prevent the server from closing?
3.  according to my logs the server's 'close' event and close() callback never fire, even after waiting overnight

Comment: i misunderstood, worker.disconnect() also works from within the worker.  however, does this not interrupt requests currently in progress?

Comment: Nope, it will just tell the server to stop passing requests to that worker and immediately start a new one.